# is it possible to struct this file with array member

Tags: c

is there any way I could struct this into file and read it using fwrite and fread

I tried some several methods but nothing happens

```
 struct Register{
 user[20][20];
 pass[20][20];
 } x[10];
```

Comment: Some type decs seem to be missing....

Comment: You could start by writing a valid `struct` definition.  The one you've presented fails to declare types for its members.

Comment: C has little in the way of introspective capability, you would need to write custom functions to encode and decode the data manually.

Comment: You don't need any introspective capability to write an object of any type with `fwrite()`, @faissaloo.

Comment: could you give me some examples with array members

Comment: @JohnBollinger You cannot simply write pointers to a file.

Comment: On the contrary, @faissaloo, you absolutely can.  Whether that's *useful* is a separate question.  But that seems beside the point -- where do you see any pointers in the OP's code?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing the problem

Comment: OT:  the word `register`, all lower case, has a special meaning in C.  so naming a struct `Register`, although it has different capitalization, is confusing and a very poor choice for a struct 'tag' name

Comment: In general, it is best to separate the struct definition from a declaration of an instance (in this case array) of that struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following proposed code may be what your looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// to avoid using 'magic' numbers
#define NUM_STRUCTS  10
#define MAX_USERS    20
#define MAX_USER_LEN 20
#define MAX_PASSS    20
#define MAX_PASS_LEN 20

struct Register
{
     char user[ MAX_USERS ][ MAX_USER_LEN ];
     char pass[ MAX_PASSS ][ MAX_PASS_LEN ];
}; 

int main( void )
{
    struct Register x[ NUM_STRUCTS ];

    // initialize structs here, then

    FILE *fp = fopen( "fileContainingStructs", "w" );
    if( !fp )
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    size_t numStructs =
        fwrite( x, sizeof( struct Register ), NUM_STRUCTS, fp );
    if( numStructs != NUM_STRUCTS )
    {
        perror( "fwrite failed" );
        fclose( fp );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fwrite successful

    fclose( fp );
}
```

Comment: Do you have solution, how you can reset the file

Comment: Reseting the file can be done by `ftruncate()` or opening the file via `fopen()`  with the "w" mode.